# NgRX - Selector x Effect execution order

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I would like to ask about one thing.

Imagine you have Effect service class like that:

```
@Injectable()
export class GeneralEffect implements OnDestroy {

    private state?: IAppState;

    saveState$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(
            logoutAction
        ),
        tap((a) => {
            console.log(this.state);
        })
    ), {dispatch: false});

    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private store: Store<IAppState>,
    ) {
        this.store.select((state) => state).subscribe((s) => {
            this.state = s;
        });
    }
}
```

My question is, is it guaranteed, that inside logoutAction effect the state will be updated? In other words, I know, that effect will be fired only after all reducers are finished ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996873/ngrx-order-of-execution-of-reducers-and-effects?rq=1)), but does it also mean, that **store select subscription** (in constructor) will also be fired **before effect**, or there might be scenario, when inisde "tap" function, there will be still old State (before logoutAction reducer)?

I know, that one solution is to add **withLatestFrom(this.store.select((state) => state))** into effects pipe, but I'm just curious how is it in order execution of Selectors observables and Effects.

Thanks